# Select with multiple cases and join time out

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the title, I am not sure what to put there.

I am trying to summarize data per year with cases & select. I am not sure this is the right way to do it. In my cases, it can be select with multiple join to check data on that year & month.

This is sample query for **January**. There are 12 query (Jan-Dec) and I union them all. If data become bigger, I thought the joined table is taking too long and my query time out.

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS INT_MONTH, 'Jan' AS STR_MONTH, 
           STATUS = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FIELD FROM TB 
                           WHERE MONTH=1 & YEAR=@year) THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Not Yet' END,
           CREATED_BY = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FIELD FROM TB 
                           WHERE MONTH=1 & YEAR=@year) 
                        THEN 'Ready' ELSE '-' END,
           CREATED_DT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FIELD FROM TB 
                           WHERE MONTH=1 & YEAR=@year) 
                        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 DT FROM FIELD WHERE MONTH=1 & YEAR=@year) ELSE NULL END,
           DATA1 = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 FIELD FROM TB INNER JOIN TB2 ON TB2.F1 = TB.F1 WHERE TB2.MONTH=1 & TB2.YEAR=@year)
                     THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Not Ready' END,
           DATA2 = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FIELD FROM TB INNER JOIN TB3 ON TB2.F1 = TB.F1 WHERE TB3.MONTH=1 & TB3.YEAR=@year) 
                      THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Not Ready' END
```

In my real query there are 3 inner join inside the cases. I simplified it here to explain the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your expected output? I think you also need to provide sample data.

Comment: Something tells me that there is a lot simpler way to do this, but it's hard to figure exactly what you want from what you've provided. If you give us your table structures and what you would like to see as a result of your query, you'll probably get a better answer. For a start, though, there's no reason to have a `TOP 1` in your `WHEN EXISTS` clause; if none exist you're doing the one thing, and if one exists you're doing the other. Since that's true, "one or more" has the same result as "one." I also doubt very much that you have to perform 12 queries and `UNION` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a month table for not use union

```
;WITH M AS (
    SELECT * FROM ( VALUES(1,'Jan'),(2,'Feb'),(3,'Mar'),(4,'Apr'),(5,'May'),(6,'Jın'),(7,'Jul'),(8,'Aug'),(9,'Sep'),(10,'Oct'),(11,'Nov'),(12,'Dec') ) M(INT_MONTH, STR_MONTH)
)
SELECT 
    M.INT_MONTH,
    M.STR_MONTH,
    CASE WHEN TB.FIELD IS NULL THEN 'Not Yet' ELSE 'Ready' END AS STATUS,
    CASE WHEN TB.FIELD IS NULL THEN '-' ELSE 'Ready' END AS CREATED_BY,
    CASE WHEN TB.FIELD IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE DT END AS CREATED_DT,
    CASE WHEN TB2.F1 IS NULL THEN 'Not Ready' ELSE 'Ready' END AS DATA1,
    CASE WHEN TB3.F1 IS NULL THEN 'Not Ready' ELSE 'Ready' END AS DATA2
FROM M
LEFT JOIN TB ON M.INT_MONTH = TB.MONTH AND TB.YEAR=@year
LEFT JOIN TB2 ON TB2.F1 = TB.F1 AND M.INT_MONTH = TB2.MONTH AND TB2.YEAR=@year
LEFT JOIN TB3 ON TB3.F1 = TB.F1 AND M.INT_MONTH = TB3.MONTH AND TB3.YEAR=@year
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: This is great, I am using OUTER APPLY instead LEFT JOIN though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your query, your query can be modified with JOINS. Please find below corresponding query. You can get an idea about how to change your query accordingly.

Also, I would recommend to change the column names YEAR, MONTH, as they are keywords in sql server. I have put square brackets around them to avoid syntax errors.

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS INT_MONTH, 'Jan' AS STR_MONTH, 
           STATUS = CASE WHEN t.Field IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Not Yet' END,
           CREATED_BY = CASE WHEN t.Field IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ready' ELSE '-' END,
           CREATED_DT = CASE WHEN t.Field IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN d.DT ELSE NULL END,
           DATA1 = CASE WHEN t2.F1 IS NOT NULL 
                     THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Not Ready' END,
           DATA2 = CASE WHEN t2.F1 IS NOT NULL 
                      THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Not Ready' END  
FROM TB AS t
LEFT JOIN DT as d
ON t.[Month] = d.[Month] and t.[year] = d.[year]
LEFT JOIN TB2 AS t2
ON t2.F1 = t.F1 and t2.[month] = t.[month] and t2.[year] = t.[year]
WHERE [Month] = 1 AND [YEAR] =  @year
```